# migration java 7 to java 8 - forEach in forEach for a HashMap in HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

My java7 code:

```
int dataIndex = 0;
final List<DataIndex> indexData = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Entry<Integer, Map<String, ModelList>> e : fusionedData.entrySet()) {
    for (final Entry<String, ModelList> e2 : e.getValue().entrySet()) {
        dataIndex++;
        indexData.add(new DataIndex(dataIndex, e2.getValue().getIds()));
    }
}
```

I try with `forEach`:

```
fusionedData.forEach(entry -> { ...??? })
```

I try with `stream` + `map`

```
fusionedData.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)...???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AtomicInteger dataIndex = new AtomicInteger();
final List<DataIndex> indexData = fusionedData.values().stream()
    .flatMap(models-> models.values().stream()) // Stream<ModelList>
    .map(ModelList::getIds)
    .map(ids -> new DataIndex(dataIndex.incrementAndGet(), ids))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ModelList>> fusionedData;
fusionedData.values() // Collection<Map<Integer, ModelList>
        .stream() // Stream<Map<Integer, ModelList>>
        .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream()) // Stream<ModelList>
        .forEach(value -> {
            // here value is instance of ModelList
            // do something with that
        });
```